# What was the reason for lseek function to return file descriptors as long integer?

Tags: c, programming, historical-unix

According to the book **Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment** :-

*"The character l in the name lseek means ‘‘long integer.’’ Before the introduction of the off_t data type, the offset argument and the return value were long integers. lseek was introduced with Version 7 when long integers were added to C. (Similar functionality was provided in Version 6 by the functions seek and tell.)"*

We know that there is a limit on the value of file descriptors.That value lies in the range **0**-**OPEN_MAX-1**.So,if earlier versions use long integer for file descriptors ,then this could mean that the maximum number of files which can be opened per process must vary according to the system word format(32 bit or 64 bit),and this means that the number of available file descriptors could be of the order of 10^18.Am I right?

Comment: What does the maximum number of open file descriptors have to do with the return type of `lseek()`? A filedescriptor is usually of the type `int`.

Comment: I think you haven't read the reference i used in my question.It says that "Before the introduction of the off_t data type, the offset argument and the return value were long integers".The return value were long integers.And the return value was a file descriptor.

Comment: Compare [V7 `lseek()`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V7-Snapshot-Development/usr/src/libc/sys/lseek.s) with [V6 `seek()`](https://github.com/dspinellis/unix-history-repo/blob/Research-V6-Snapshot-Development/usr/source/s5/seek.s).  The return value is an error code. A `long` error in V7, but still no file descriptor.

Comment: You aren't understanding what I am trying to say.I quoted a reference from the book and that book  says it so.That is not what I am saying.The book says that lseek returns file descriptor value.

Comment: Your quote is from p. 67 (in the 3rd edition) of the book. Nowhere there does it say that `lseek()` or `seek()` returned a file descriptor. It says only that the return value was a `long` in V7. It doesn't even make sense that `lseek()` or `seek()` _returned_ a file descriptor. What would the use of that be?

Comment: @ShanifAnsari You're confusing parameters with the return value.

Comment: Satō Katsura, Stephen Kitt and Kusalananda are right; you (Shanif Ansari) are confused.  The ``lseek`` system call does not *return* file descriptors.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is founded on a false premise; it asks “Why is this true?” of a statement that isn’t true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lseek`’s `long` parameter and return value are both *offsets* in the file; the addition of `long` didn’t have any impact on file descriptors.

Varying word size did have an impact on the size of usable offsets; see [`lseek64`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lseek64.3.html) for a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is a misunderstanding.

The complete quote from the book is

> The three symbolic constants—`SEEK_SET`, `SEEK_CUR`, and `SEEK_END`—were introduced
>   with System V. Prior to this, whence was specified as 0 (absolute), 1 (relative to the current
>   offset), or 2 (relative to the end of file). Much software still exists with these numbers hard
>   coded.
>
> The character `l` in the name `lseek` means ‘‘long integer.’’ Before the introduction of the
>   `off_t` data type, the **offset argument** and **the return value** were long integers. lseek was
>   introduced with Version 7 when long integers were added to C. (Similar functionality was
>   provided in Version 6 by the functions `seek` and `tell`.)

Nowhere in the text does it say anything about the return value being a file descriptor at any point in time.